# Your database settings don't appear to be correct. All green, but still error!

Tags: wordpress, error, database, install

trying to install CiviCRM with Wordpress and I get the red DB error BUT all the line items are green.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
WP: 4.9.10
CiviCRM: 4.7.30 Wordpress
Mysql: 5.7 on Azure
```

*Added comment:*

I also ran this:

```
<?php
echo "* SQL CONNECT TEST **";
include('./config.php');
// print_r(get_defined_constants(true));
#phpinfo();
$dbcnx = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$dbcnx)
{
          print ("<hr /><p>Param(s): " . DB_HOST ." / ". DB_USER ." / ". DB_PASSWORD ." / ". DB_NAME . "</p>\n");
          die ("<hr /><p>Error:" . mysqli_connect_errno() . "</p>\n");
}
echo "<p>Connected to the database server!</p>\n";
echo "</p>\n";
echo "<p>End of script!</p>";
?>
```

Came out clean, connected and all (config.php is a copy of the Wordpress config file)

So I checked to see if somehow CiviCRM was using mysql_connect() instead of mysql*i*_connect(), but it's not.

Really at a loss here :-|

[image: All green, but still red...]

Comment: Do you use a port other than the default one (3306)? There is an issue about that in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/46. Have you tried an up to date version of CiviCRM? 4.7.30 is well out of security updates.

Comment: I will try a new version today. And no everything is default, which is why I'm baffled ( not my first CC install ).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It looks like at the present time you will need to make a small hack to get the installer to be happy. The "does the server exist check" does NOT use the username/password and merely tries to connect as anonymous (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.16.2/install/index.php#L1038). On azure this returns an error 9002, as opposed to the usual 1045 which gets skipped by the next line.

So you should be able to temporarily change that line to

`$conn = $this->connect($server, 'username@server', 'your password');`

and then after install you can change it back. I don't have an azure database to test if that is sufficient, but just doing a command line test it returns the usual error 1045 so should work.

See also [CiviCRM on Azure Not Finding the Server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31794/civicrm-on-azure-not-finding-the-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Based on your screenshot it looks like you have a "control character" as the first character of your server name, which usually happens when you copy and paste from a website page. i.e. a character that isn't actually a letter but might be a tab or non-ascii character.

In any case the error says it can't find mysql on that server, so check that the server name is correct.

Comment: Well, I could understand that, if it wasn't because it's all copied from VIM from the wp-config.php file, and the Wordpress site *is working*.

Comment: Also, the lines (in green) states
    Are the access credentials correct?    OK
    MySQL version at least 5.1      OK (MySQL 5.6.39.0)
    Is auto_increment_increment set to 1    OK
    Is the provided database name valid?   OK
    Does MySQL thread_stack meet minimum (192k) OK
    Can I access/create the database?    OK (Database 'xxxxx' exists)
    Can I access/create InnoDB tables in the database? OK
    Can I create temporary tables in the database?  OK
    Can I create lock tables in the database?   OK
    Can I create triggers in the database?   OK

Comment: So it's connecting, it seems like.

Even the error "Can't find the a MySQL server on ..." seems a little off, given that it states the version is MySQL 5.6.39.0

Comment: Oh shoot, so sorry, forgot comments dont format...! Argh

Comment: +1 for vim (he he). But I don't have any more insight to the problem other than the servername.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try @Demerit  !

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1206

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your civicrm_settings.php file is not writable, or is duplicated? If you run php_info() does it confirm that you're running MySQL 5.7? What is your OS?